# Add reference to javascript file in dynamicaly generated HTML page in Delphi VCL application

Tags: javascript, delphi

I'm making a Delphi XE5 VCL Forms Application and there is a `TIdHTTPServer` on the main form and a `CommandGet` of the `IdHTTPServer` procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.IdHTTPServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
var responce: TStringList;
begin
if pos('someString', ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams) > 0 then
   begin
      responce:= TStringList.Create;
      try
         responce.Add('<html>');
         responce.Add('<head>');
         responce.Add('<title>Index</title>');
         responce.Add('<script src="E:\ProjectFolder\script.js"></script>')
         responce.Add('</head>');
         // HTML content
         responce.Add('</html>');
         AResponseInfo.ContentText := responce.Text;
      finally
         responce.Free;
      end;
  end;
end;
```

When I change the directory of the project the .js file is not visible by the browser. My question is how to set the reference to the .js file to make it avaliable when I change projects directory.

Comment: Traditionally paths in HTML are in Posix format (i.e. /project/scripts/scripts.js). Avoid drive letters too. I'd make a subfolder called scripts, place my JS file in that and then reference the script `<script src="scripts/script.js"></script>`

Comment: the resource location must be relative to the resource root directory, it has nothing to do with the real folder structure on the server

Comment: @Andy_D I moved the .js files to another directory then I set the path to the javascript file projectDirectoryPath := GetCurrentDir + '\scripts\script.js'; and when I tested in chrome and the result was: Not allowed to load local resource: + the file path (which is ok).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward solution is to include the script in html:

```
var
  scriptContent: TStringList;

...
responce.Add('<script type="text/javascript">');
scriptContent := TStringList.Create;
try
  scriptContent.LoadFromFile('<name of the script file>');
  responce.AddStrings(scriptContent);
finally
  scriptContent.Free;
end;
responce.Add('</script>');
```

Comment: Embedding the script file directly in the HTML has many disadvantages (security, resource usage, caching).

Answer (score 4):

Traditionally paths in HTML are in Posix format (i.e. /project/scripts/scripts.js). Avoid drive letters too. I'd make a subfolder called scripts, place my JS file in that and then reference the script